# Is there a getter for an entire worksheet or range including formulas, values, merges, formatting etc. in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to make a backup of an entire worksheet, including formulas, values, formatting, row and column size, cell merges, etc. so that when a user is finished editing I can reset the sheet. Currently I'm using a `Range.getFormulas()` to create a stringified object (that I can then paste into my code as a constant) to reset all of the content of the cells, but if the user changes the row size or deletes a cell, I'd like to be able to quickly rebuild the entire sheet without iterating through rows and columns (Apps Script is too slow for that). My previous method was to create a duplicate of the sheet and simply hide it, but someone can still unhide and edit that.

I've been digging through the documentation, but I haven't found anything useful. To sum up, I'd like to have something like this:

```
function resetHandler() {
    var destinationWorksheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A1:H132"),
        backupWorksheet = [...object...];
    backupWorksheet.copyTo(destinationWorksheet);
}
```

where "[...object...]" is the output of a getter that contains the entire sheet as an object. I tried `JSON.stringify(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadSheetByName("Workorder").getRange("A1:H132"))` but it just outputs "{}" since the `Range` class is all private.

If there isn't a way, I can always fall back on a hidden backup sheet.

Comment: Why not `copyTo` a backup Spreadsheet?  You can recall from the backup also.  `copyTo` is the only way to get everything about a sheet at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

I've created an example where a sheet has formulas, conditional format and data validation.  Using testCopyTo I copy Sheet1 to a Backup spreadsheet.  All attributes are copied.  Using testCopyFrom first copy from the Backup spreadsheet then copy the range within the spreadsheet and finally delete the copy of the backup sheet.

**Before restore**

[image]

**After restore**

[image]

**Script**

```
function testCopyTo() {
  try {
    let source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let dest = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx.......");
    source.copyTo(dest);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function testCopyFrom() {
  try {
    let dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx.......").getSheetByName("Copy of Sheet1");
    source.copyTo(dest);
    source = dest.getSheetByName("Copy of Copy of Sheet1");
    dest = dest.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    source.getDataRange().copyTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1));
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(source);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a neat workaround. I could backup the worksheet into a variable as the spreadsheet is opened, and use that. Only issue is that doesn't help the situation of the user editing the sheet and closing it without resetting. I'd need to set it to reset automatically on close, which I can do

Answer (score 0):

## There is no Apps Script method to retrieve a spreadsheet by its name, you need to retrieve it by [id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) or url

- Keep in ind that in Google Drive, multiple spreadsheets with the same name can exist within a folder, this is why it would not make any sense to try and retrieve a spreadsheet by its name
- Instead, you need to use the method [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) or `openByUrl(url)`  (less recommended)
- To get a sheet from an external spreadsheet and copy it to the current one, you can do the following:

```js
function resetHandler() {
    var destinationWorksheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    backupWorksheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("123456789").getSheetByName("The Name of the Sheet");
    backupWorksheet.copyTo(destinationWorksheet);
}
```

where `123456789` is the id of the backup spreadsheet which you can find among others in the url in the address bar, which looks something like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1234456789/edit#gid=1392862199`

- To copying a range from a sheet from an external spreadsheet into a sheet in the curent spreadsheet with `copyTo` is not possible, you can only use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) respectively, however this will not copy the formatting. Also for the formulas, you need to perform additoinally [getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas) and [setFormulas(formulas)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas).

UPDATE

If you would like to copy a range from one sheet into another sheet of the same spreadsheet, you can modify your code as following:

```js
function resetHandler() {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var destinationSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSpreadSheetByName("Workorder");
  var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange("A1:H132");
  var backupWorksheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSpreadSheetByName("Backup").getRange("A1:H132");
  var backupRange = backupWorksheet.getRange("A1:H132");
  backupRange.copyTo(destinationRange);
}
```

- The main problem with your code was that you mixed up the methods [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) for ranges with [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet).
- Both methods have the same name, but the first copies a range into another range (into the same sheet or another sheet of the same spreadsheet; overwriting the previous contents), while the other one inserts a whole (additoinal) sheet from a spreadsheet into the same or different spreadsheet
- Have a careful look at the sample in the documentation for appplying the correct syntax in each case
- Also: The method `getSpreadSheetByName()` does not exist, it is [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- Careful with the wording: Google talks about sheets and spreadsheets, which are the equivalents of Excel worksheets and workbooks respectively.

Comment: It is possible to copyTo from another spreadsheet see the scripts below.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm copying from a Worksheet inside the spreadsheet I'm working, not an entire spreadsheet.

Comment: @TheWizEd: It is possible to copy a sheet from one spreadsheet to another, but not a range - or in other words, the method [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) for ranges only works within the same spreadsheet. But of course, copying first the whole sheet to the current spreadsheet and then a range out of it is a great workaround.

Comment: @Dexter: I got confused because youw ere trying to use the mehtod `getSpreadSheetByName` - I updated my solution now.